# Is there a docker log viewer or debug mode for windows?

Tags: windows, docker, debugging, command-line-interface

It seems the Docker Desktop is always being updated and often with bugs so it is not working as it was previously. The default install on Windows is mostly a black box and you can look at the GUI, but it isn't very helpful in learning what is happening or where it is in starting when it says "restarting" for example.  Preface of the question is that Docker is targeted towards developers, but then they wrap it into this dumbed down GUI that makes the service a black box to developers. I would prefer to start it some sort of debug mode in a console window and only when I want to interact via the GUI use those features. Is there a way to use docker from a more programmer friendly console interface on Windows?

Comment: They wrap it up in this "dumbed down GUI" because docker doesn't run on Windows, the UI handles creation of a VM which runs the docker daemon. If you want to not use this UI, you can always create a VM yourself, install some linux distribution and install docker inside.

Answer (score 1):

Open an elevated command prompt and then run `sc.exe qc docker` to query the current configuration info for docker service.

From the output of the above command take the `BINARY_PATH_NAME` and modify it using the below steps.

`1. Escape each " with \`

`2. Add -D at the end`

`3. Keep the whole command in " "`

After modifying it run the command and then restart the `docker` service.

***Example***

1. Let's say `BINARY_PATH_NAME : "C:\Proram Files\Docker\dockerd.exe" --run-service`
2. After modifying it needs to be like this

   `sc.exe config docker binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe\" --run-service -D"`
3. After executing the above commands restart the docker service.

   `sc.exe stop docker`

   `sc.exe start docker`

Comment: Where is the c in "sc.exe c docker" documented? I don't see that under sc documentation and nothing happens if I run "sc c" to trigger help. Wondering if that should be a "qc" ...